# Can't select element selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

how can i select
Armen Khl

using python with selenium

```
<table id="ads-link-1091937" class="work-serf" data-status="inactive">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="ads_1091937">
    <td width="18">
       <div class="ybprosm" title="Просмотр видео"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div id="start-ads-1091937">
         <span onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; funcjs['start_youtube'](1091937, '0106019a4aaa39706c917c8bce23c111', 'ads-start', 'ads');" title="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LltHv-MPp_E" style="cursor:pointer;color:#006699;" data-cf-modified-2376def8386a7bac71794558-="">Armen Khl</span>          <br>
         <span class="serf-text">Просмотр видеоролика</span>
```

view_text = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@class="work-serf"]'/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/span)

plz tell me what i wrong in this line code

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To print the text ***Armen Khl*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.work-serf > tbody > tr td > div > span[onclick][title]").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@class="work-serf"]/tbody/tr//td/div/span[@onclick and @title]").text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

---

Ideally to extract the text ***Armen Khl*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.work-serf > tbody > tr td > div > span[onclick][title]"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class="work-serf"]/tbody/tr//td/div/span[@onclick and @title]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)